# MySQL database. can't add foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables movies and cinema. In the cinema table, there is a primary key called cinema_id. I am trying to make this primary key from the cinema table a foreign key in the movies table.
So I used

```
alter table movies
add foreign key(cinema_id)
references cinema(cinema_id)
```

but I get an error message that says:

> #1072 - Key column 'cinema_id' doesn't exist in table

so I added a column and then tried to create a foreign key again and there was an error message that said :

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

I have already checked the column type and it is the same. Can someone please help me with this? I have no idea what to do.

Comment: While adding FK you must check that all data passes its contraints. Use `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` before your query and set it to 1 after it if you want to force.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk I do not understand what SET foreign_key_checks = 0; would do?

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but has Google stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong syntax. You have to create a constraint and not simply add a foreign key.. 
Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE MOVIES ADD CONSTRAINT MOVIES_CINEMA_FK
FOREIGN KEY (CINEMA_ID) 
REFERENCES CINEMA(CINEMA_ID);
```

[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Hi, i tried this and it still gave me the same error

Comment: Do you have any record in the table `movies`? If yes, you must make sure, that the values are also in the table `cinema`

Comment: I do have dummy data in both the cinema and movie table.So the columns in the movie table have to be in the cinema table as well?

Comment: yes.. every value of `movies.cinema_id` has to be in `cinema.cinema_id` otherwise you have a constraint violation.

Comment: ok, are you saying that all the columns in the movies table has to be in the cinema table as well?

Comment: Not all the columns.  All the values in the cinema_id in the movies table have to have exist in the cinema_id column in the cinema table.  For instance if cinema_id 23 is in the movies table then there needs to be a cinema_id 23 in the cinema table.